# Is there a way to use Iphone Touch ID sensor to sign documents

Tags: ios, fingerprint, touch-id

I am interested in developing an application that uses Touch ID sensor, to collect people fingerprint and use it as they have signed a document, or say they have received an UPS package, for example. So far, my search found the touch id sensor is to be used internally only by Apple built in apps and to unlock the phone. I could not get any official confirmation that I am not allowed to use the Touch ID sensor with my own application. Is it possible ?

With that in mind, I don't mean to access phone's security storage area or acess any fingerprint stored in the phone. I just want to get the fingerprint of a prove an event happened (like a person received a package) and keep that info inside my apps database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The touchID sensor and it's data are only available to Apple. There is no availability for developers.

Comment: Is there any plan to make it available to 3rd party apps ?

Comment: There is no access as of iOS 7.x. There are only two things it does: 1) unlock the device and authenticate for in-app purchase.As I see it, it really is a security issue. Perhaps they will open it up, pay attention to WWDC next week.

Comment: iOS 8 includes an API for requesting fingerprint ID from the user from within your own apps. However, this just gives you a simple yes/no response, so is still not useful for your purpose unfortunately (assuming I understand what it is you were trying to achieve!)